# Returned value from promise is not what is expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

I have some logic where I'm trying to build a "person" object and I have a method called `getProvider` where i'm basically fetching a provider from mongo and assiging it to `person.provider`.

Since the call to mongo is async, i'm trying to use promises. The value seems to be correct everywhere i've logged it except in my `.then` method. It shows `{"source": {}}` and I have no idea why.

Here's my output:

```
data = 
MYPROVIDER
provider = 
MYPROVIDER
after addProvider
{"source":{}}


...
configDone.promise.then(function () {
    return addProvider();
}).then(function() {
    console.log('after addProvider');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(people[0].provider)); // SHOWS {"source": {}}. WHY IS IT DOING THIS?
    callback(null, people);
}).fail(function (err) {
    callback(err);
});


function addProvider() {

    var promises = [];

    people.forEach(function(person){
        promises.push(person.provider = getProvider(person.id, db));
    });

    return Q.all(promises).spread(function(provider) {
        console.log('provider = ');
        console.log(provider); // SHOWS CORRECT PROVIDER HERE
    });
}

// Gets a provider for a specific person id
var getProvider = function(id, db) {

    var def = Q.defer();

    db.collection('providerLists').findOne({id: id}, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            def.reject(err);
        } else {
            console.log('data = ');
            console.log(data.ListName);  // SHOWS CORRECT VALUE
            def.resolve(data.ListName);
        }
    });

    return def.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`people[0].provider` should be pointing at a resolved promise. If you attach a `then` handler to it you will see the expected provider value:

```
people[0].provider.then(function(provider) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(provider);
});
```

If you wanted to have the provider to be a value on each person of the people array you could update your addProvider function as follows:

```
function addProvider() {

var promises = [];

people.forEach(function(person){
    promises.push(getProvider(person.id, db)
      .then(function(provider) {
        person.provider = provider;
      });
});

return Q.all(promises).spread(function(provider) {
    console.log('provider = ');
    console.log(provider); // SHOWS CORRECT PROVIDER HERE
});
}
```

Comment: I don't want provider to be on the people array as there is a specific provider for each person. So how would I loop through and assign that way?

Comment: `configDone.promise.then(function () {
     return addProvider();
    }).then(function() {
     console.log('after addProvider');
     console.log(JSON.stringify(patients[0].provider));
   patients[0].then(function(provider) {
    console.log(provider);
   })
     callback(null, people);
    }).fail(function (err) {
     callback(err);
    });` This gives the error `Error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'`

Comment: @Catfish: You'd need to use `patients[0].provider.then(function(provider) { console.log(provider); })` - the single patient is indeed not a promise.

Comment: Ok so that works with @Bergi's edits. I don't really care for the look of this style. Is there a way I can refactor my `addProvider` method so that I can actually set the `person.provider` in that method rather than in my `config.promise.then` block?

Comment: @Catfish added method where you have the provider property of each person be the provider that is the result of the promise call to my answer.